Manage favorite live channels on Android TV
I've 2 new Android TVs (Android 11) from different brands, and during the 1st power-on, several questions were raised and the search of channels and Internet was configured.
However, I skipped to step of setting up a Google account.
At the moment, the TV is working, but I can't see any option to set up a favorite list of channels.
Unexpectedly, from Home, "Settings", "Channel", I can see only:

Parental controls
Open source licenses
Version

In the past with other Android TV, I was able to set favorite channels without adding a Google account.
Is there any option to manage channels?

It was possible to do this without setting up a Google account

Watching a live TV channel

Press the "menu" button on the remote (maybe 3 lines)

(By default)  “TV options”, a horizontal menu appears on the screen.
(this menu is also vertical and has other entries, one above and the other below)

Move up to the “TV options” row, then select “Channels”

then “Add to my favorites”


The option was there, but IMHO the GUI and UX are so terrible that even looking for something specific, I was not able to see it nor was I expecting it in this way.
